# Cannot get mouse functions to work

Tags: mouseevent, abstract-class, mouselistener

I'm trying to write a program that measures reaction time by clicking on a circle when it changes color but I can't get any of the mouse functions to work. Any idea how to write the code so that I can track the coordinates of the mouse when it clicks? Here's the error when I try to compile the program now. *MouseListener is abstract; cannot be instantiated*
    *MouseListener circle = new MouseListener();*

```
            import java.util.*;
            import java.io.*;
            import java.awt.*;
            import java.awt.event.*;
            import java.util.Random;
            import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
            import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
            import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

            public class Stopwatch
            {
                public static int windowX = 900; 
                public static int windowY = 700;

                public static void main(String args[])
                {
                    GfxApp gfx = new GfxApp();
                    gfx.setSize(900,700);
                    gfx.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {public void
                    windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {System.exit(0);}});
                    gfx.show();
                }
            }

            class GfxApp extends Frame
            {
                public void paint(Graphics g) 
                {           
                    Timer.drawgreen(g);
                    Timer.pause();
                    Timer.drawred(g);

                }
            }

            class Timer
            {
                public static int circlex = 300;
                public static int circley = 200;
                public static int radius = 250;

                public static void drawgreen(Graphics g)
                {
                    g.setColor(new Color(0,255,0));
                    g.fillOval(circlex, circley, radius, radius);
                }

                public static void drawred(Graphics g)
                {
                    g.setColor(new Color(255,0,0));
                    g.fillOval(circlex, circley, radius, radius);
                }

                public static void pause()
                {
                    Random rand = new Random();

                    int k = rand.nextInt(301);

                    for(double i = 0; i < 500 + k; i += .000001)
                    {
            //                      delay
                    }
                }
            }

            class Mouse
            {
                MouseListener circle = new MouseListener();

                public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent e)
                {
                }
                public void mouseEntered (MouseEvent e)
                {
                }
                public void mouseExited (MouseEvent e)
                {
                }
                public void mousePressed (MouseEvent e)
                {
                }
                public void mouseReleased (MouseEvent e)
                {
                }
            }
```

Comment: The error tells you what is wrong, you need to either create anonymous inner implementation of the interface, or try some other class (maybe this ain't what you want).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to implement your mouse listener to your Frame class and work with it there.
MouseListener is interface not class so it can't be instantiat.

This is example with KeyListener

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Window extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -8255319694373975038L;
public static boolean change = false;

KPanel kp = new KPanel();
KeyListen kl = new KeyListen();
Rect r[];

public Window() {   
    JFrame w = new JFrame("okno");
    w.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    w.setVisible(true);
    w.setSize(500, 500);
    w.setResizable(false);
    w.getContentPane().add(kp);
    w.addKeyListener(kl);
}

}



class KeyListen implements KeyListener {

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to just track one set of coordinates? If so then perhaps something like below would help...

```
double xClick = 0;
double yClick = 0;

private MouseListener click = new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                //Get the Mouse Location and store it.
                double xClick = e.getX();  //mouse's X location
                double yClick = e.getY(); //mouse's Y location 
      }
};
```

Then you'd need to detect the xClick and the yClick variable and whether they interesect the circle shape.

```
if(ellipse.contains(e.getX(), e.getY())){
                //Do Something in here...
}
```

If you want to track all the mouse click locations then use an array of doubles or and array of Point2D's.

Hope this helps.

Also use either mouseReleased or mousePressed for the click detection. MouseClicked only works if the user doesn't move between pressing and releasing.